# R - Delete column in dataframe if column name contains NA

Tags: r, dataframe

I currently have a dataframe with 350 columns. Due to the way that I import the dataframe, there are several columns with NA as the column name. Therefore, R names them NA, NA.1, NA.2, etc. I would like to remove any columns in the dataframe that have NA as the first two letters. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df[, grep("^(NA)", names(df), value = TRUE, invert = TRUE)]
```

Comment: Nice use (and concise) of grepgrep's capabilities.